# Menu not styling. New menus functionality giving me a headache

Tags: php, functions, menus, troubleshooting

I can't find a good tutorial on the new menu handling functions, and the ones I found don't seem to work for me. What am I doing wrong?

In my `functions.php`:

(I'm using the Blank Slate theme as a framework; I'll figure out later what's noise, but it's pretty minimal -- hence the name)

```
function blankslate_register_menus() {
    register_nav_menus( array( 'main-menu' => __( 'Main Menu', 'blankslate' )));
}
```

Next, on `header.php`:

```
<nav>
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu' ) ); ?>
</nav>
```

And finally, testing my `style.css` for every possible option:

```
.main-menu, .main-menu *, #main-menu *, #main-menu {
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

Does nothing. The menu items are simply listed like a simple HTML `<ul>` would be. I've followed this tutorial: http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/06/01/goodbye-headaches-hello-menus which is the opnly decent and recent one I found, but I don't see what I've done different.

(if I try the class `.menu`, it works, so the problem is in what I'm assuming the classes are?)

Also, the tutorial mentions a whole lot of parameters that cane be added to the `register_nav_menu()` function, like custom tags, and using `<div>` by default, yet no mention of how to actually set them.

Any help?

My theme is almost done and I've been stuck on a freaking menu function all day... I'd've made a menu old school by now :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This:**

```
<nav>
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu' ) ); ?>
</nav>
```

.

**Should be:**

```
<nav>
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu', 'menu_class' => 'main_menu' ) ); ?>
</nav>
```

**The css:**

```
.main_menu {
   font-size: 14px; // example
}
```

.

Learn more here: [wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)

Best of luck,
Sagive

Comment: Thank you. I misunderstood the documentation and didn't quite understand what the function spits out.

Comment: no problem mate - glad you got it working ;)